# Direct and Indirect reports using JS. Javascript nested loops with arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, nested

```
    const employees = [
  {
    id: 1,
    directReports: [2, 3]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    directReports: [4]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    directReports: []
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    directReports: [5]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    directReports: []
  }
];
```

Requested Output:

```
    employees = [
      {
        id: 1,
        directReports: [2, 3],
        reports: [2,3,4,5]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        directReports: [4],
        reports: [4,5]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        directReports: [],
        reports: []
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        directReports: [5],
        reports: [5]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        directReports: [],
        reports: []
      }
    ];
```

I want to add a new array inside the objects listing all the directReports of the parent, child, and children. I was able to get all the children but what if my last element is the parent of the first element. I am getting the max call stack reached. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
let childReports = [];

const getReports = emp => {
  if (emp.directReports === undefined) return;
  emp.directReports.forEach(report => {
    if (!childReports.includes(report)) {
      childReports.push(report);
    }
    const employ = employees.filter(e => e.id === report);
    getReports(employ[0]);
  });
};

employees.forEach(employee => {
  if (!!employee.directReports) {
    childReports.push(...employee.directReports);
    getReports(employee);
    employee.reports = childReports;
    childReports = [];
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like a case for reduce with a nested search.  But what is the code you tried?  Start by posting that...

Comment: is there a restrction on the input data that it MUST be tree structured? IE reports can't be circular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like....

```js
const EMPLOYEES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    directReports: [2, 3]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    directReports: [4]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    directReports: []
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    directReports: [5]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    directReports: []
  }
];
 
const getReports = (employee, employees) => {
  return (employee && employee.directReports) ? employee.directReports.concat( // get direct reports (null checked)
    employee.directReports.reduce((reports, id) => { // concat direct reports reduced
      // to their direct reports recursively
      return reports.concat(getReports(employees.find(e => e.id === id), employees));
    }, [])
  ) : []; // or just an empty array
}

const withReports = EMPLOYEES.map(employee => {
  return {
    ...employee,
    reports: getReports(employee, EMPLOYEES)
  };
}) 
    
console.log(withReports)
```

An assumption here is that you can't have a circular report structure, as this will never break if you do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar approach to the one from bryan60, but using the ids as the primary means of passing information rather than the employee object itself.  It also uses a significantly different code style:

```js
const getReports = (
  employees,
  id, 
  direct = employees .find (({id: id2}) => id == id2) .directReports || []
) => [... direct, ... direct .flatMap (id => getReports (employees, id))]

const transform = (employees) => 
  employees .map ((e) => ({... e, reports: getReports (employees, e.id)}))

const EMPLOYEES = [{id: 1, directReports: [2, 3]}, {id: 2, directReports: [4]}, {id: 3, directReports: []}, {id: 4, directReports: [5]}, {id: 5, directReports: []}]

console .log(
  transform (EMPLOYEES)
)
```